# Closure: Why does John Cage judge Beethoven wrong for not unfolding music moment by moment?

Tags: discussion

I don't judge my question as being unclear?

I am not sure if [this moderator who unilaterally closed](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/62369/why-does-john-cage-judge-beethoven-wrong-for-not-unfolding-music-moment-by-momen?noredirect=1#comment95606_62369), suggests posting the 3 related questions separately? I can if this is desired.

Also, my question does concern music theory?

Answer (score 2):

Unclear has a number of meanings on Stack Exchange.

Most importantly, yes, you need to post one question, not multiple. This is a pretty specific requirement across SE. Otherwise you could get multiple answers each answering one part, and that is not what we want. This is very much one of the reasons we close questions. And just to tackle the use of the word "unilaterally" - yes, mod actions are almost all unilateral, by definition.

Then once we get into your questions, which you appear to have numbered from 3 to 5 - which doesn't help with clarity, the final one is not on topic here as it is entirely subjective. You are asking us to identify what meaning he intended from that phrase, and as he doesn't appear to have explained it anywhere, that's just not going to work.

Your question 4 has similar issues - it isn't music theory. It is opinion from an individual who specifically set out to cause shock and publicity. Who knows what he meant?

Your question 3 may be answerable - it feels rather subjective, but it may be worth asking as a new question.