# Are questions on writing by composers on-topic?

Tags: discussion

As https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/7003/1055 and https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/7001/1055 were unilaterally migrated, I thought to check.

Comment: I think this has an answer at [Seemliness check: Why did Boulez judge Bartók's Violin Concerto to have “weaknesses, but also no contradictions”?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2994/seemliness-check-why-did-boulez-judge-bart%c3%b3ks-violin-concerto-to-have-weaknes). Another relevant question is [Closure: Why does John Cage judge Beethoven wrong for not unfolding music moment by moment?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2832/closure-why-does-john-cage-judge-beethoven-wrong-for-not-unfolding-music-moment).

Answer (score 3):

You keep on asking this same question, with only tiny differences.

Those questions are not on topic here. If you insist on asking those types of questions, they will be migrated, you may lose asking privileges, and you may be suspended again.

There are questions about writing by composers that are on topic here. You can have a look at them and see why those migrated ones are different.

And @topomorto's comment is very valid.